# Can we use a global gradle-wrapper.properties file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I can put a global `gradle.properties` in my `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.gradle\gradle.properties` which will be used by all my projects.

Can I do something similar for the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file? Normally I will use the same gradle version in all my projects and don't want to update the gradle version in all projects seperately everytime a new gradle version comes out...

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not supported by the Gradle Wrapper. If you want to go that direction you can just have a global install of Gradle. The big benefit of using the wrapper is, that you have the version of gradle defined in the wrapper script and that script lives in the repository of your project and is therefore under version control as the rest of your code.

A global wrapper file contradicts this benefit.